# Reference to overloaded function (or procedure)

Tags: delphi, anonymous-function, overloading, typechecking

I use the type

```
type
  TRealFunction = reference to function(const X: extended): extended;
```

a lot in my code. Suppose I have a variable

```
var
  rfcn: TRealFunction;
```

and try to assign `Math.ArcSec` to it:

```
rfcn := ArcSec;
```

This works just as expected in Delphi 2009, but now I tried to compile it in Delphi 10.2, and the compiler gets upset:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(42): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TRealFunction' and 'ArcSec'
```

The difference, it seems, is that `ArcSec` is overloaded in Delphi 10.2: it comes in `single`, `double`, and `extended` flavours. It seems like the compiler doesn't like references to overloaded functions (or procedures) of this kind (too similar types?).

However, if I redefine

```
type
  TRealFunction = function(const X: extended): extended;
```

it compiles just fine.

Of course, there are obvious workarounds here: I could define

```
function ArcSec(const X: extended): extended; inline;
begin
  result := Math.ArcSec(X);
end;
```

or I could just write

```
rfcn := function(const X: extended): extended
  begin
    result := Math.ArcSec(x);
  end;
```

Still, this is a lot of code to write. Is there a simpler workaround?

Comment: No, AFAIK, there isn't.

Comment: If you define TRealFunction not as reference but simply as TRealFunction = function(const X: extended): extended; then rfcn := ArcSec will work ok

Comment: @DmLam: I know, I even wrote that in the Q! :)

Comment: Suppose this wasn't an overloaded function. The compiler would have to generate some code to convert the non reference function to be a reference function. In effect it will write the exact same code as the final block in your question, and compile that. So you may as well do the same.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using Extended?

Comment: @David: That's true, I just dislike having to type a lot to express my intent. Regarding the type, I use `extended` since I fancy the additional precision and range (in particular), and I still use Delphi 2009 (with no 64-bit support) as my main tool. In the future, I'd love a native binary128 type.

Comment: You'll pay for it in performance though. But if you are using reference functions then you probably don't much care about performance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I know. I am a bit restrictive about reference functions, but they sure are awfully convenient to work with.

Comment: They are convenient. I wanted to convert to them exclusively, over of object method pointers, but the perf was not good enough in my setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
type
  TRealFunction = function(const X: extended): extended;
const
  rc : TRealFunction = Math.ArcSec;
type
  TRealFunctionRef = reference to function(const X: Extended) : Extended;

var
  rfcn: TRealFunctionRef;
begin
  rfcn := rc;
  ...
```

It requires an extra type declaration, but perhaps it is worth the effort.

Comment: An additional type declaration doesn't bother me (since that I need to do only once). The main effort here is the declaration of the constants -- one per "obnoxious" function. Still, this is much nicer than the naïve workarounds I mentioned in the Q. In particular, the `const`s can be made local to the procedure in which I need them.

Comment: Similarly, one can define a "conversion" function `function MakeFcn(const ARealFunction: TRealFunction): TRealFunctionRef; inline;
begin
  result := ARealFunction;
end;`, but this seems to cause quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: Since this appears to be the best possible workaround, I have given it a green check mark! :)

Comment: If it matters, the `TRealFunction` declaration could be omitted and the `const` could include `function(const X: extended): extended` as type instead.